# Searchbox goes under the hamburger menu at maximum width 991

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added a searchbox to sticky navbar.

[Here is the web](http://www.ptctour.com/prozim/index2.html)

[image]

When the screen is smaller than 991 search box goes under the hamburger menu icon. 
[image]

How i can put those in the same line?

Comment: share live link or code here, its not possible the check your html structure from just image

Comment: Sorry. http://www.ptctour.com/prozim/index2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this css

```
@media (max-width: 991px){
    #logo{
        float: right;
        width: auto;
    }
    .search_bar_list{
        position: relative;
        left: 28px;
    }
    header a.open_close{
        top: 10px
    }
}
```